# Looking for strategies to check if a system has been restarted

Tags: c#, theory, application-restart

I am writing an installer for my application. This installer needs to install various components and some of them require a system reboot before the next component has been installed.

The user has the option to deny a restart and do it on their own later, which is where I'm hitting a wall at the moment.

I've first considered creating some lock file or a registry entry, which on the surface level sounds doable, however if the user denies a restart and reboots at a later time through whatever way, then the registry object / file aren't deleted. Which means that when the user restarts my installer, then the installer has no way to know whether the system has been restarted or not.

My next idea was to use .NET's System.Threading.Mutex, which I thought would persist in memory after my installer processes has been finished, which was a naive approach because the mutex is cleared from the system when the reference count is reduced to 0. This would imply I need to fork another process which remains in memory holding that mutex until the user either kills the process or restarts. This seems like a bad idea...

Are there any short and sweet strategies that people use to achieve this sort of thing?

Haven't found any relevant articles here either by the way. I need some type of lock object or in memory object that persists beyond my application's lifetime but also only until the system has been rebooted.

Comment: I've never seen an application that actually performed a check that the user has restarted the system. They simply give a "helpful" warning when installation finishes and if the user ignores it, then it's their own fault if the application doesn't run properly

Comment: @UnholySheep I know what you mean, however an installation steps requires a registry edit for the stornvme driver. This edit doesn't update unless the system has been restarted. Which also means that the subsequent installation steps will fail. Now I could just force the system to restart and warn the user, however my boss insists on it being a friends yes or no messagebox. Knowing our users this will only lead to issues down the road, so my plan was to lock the installer until a reboot has taken place

Comment: There's a Win32 API function that sets a file to be deleted on restart. Create a file, mark it for deletion on reboot, and if it's still there, they haven't rebooted yet. Use [MoveFileExW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefileexw) with NULL for the new file name and the MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT flag. It's possible to delete the file by other means, but the user would have to know which file to delete, so put it somewhere that's not obvious and give it a name that's not obvious.

Comment: @madreflection That's a great solution thank you! I ended up using a second registry entry which holds the creation time of the lock (i,e of when the installer hit the reboot state) and now whenver it starts it just compares the reboot time of the computer with the timestamp in the registry entry. Kind of inelegant in my opinion but it works ^^.